# Trying to understand keras SimpleRNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a medical longitudinal data on which I am doing a research.
To start with I am working with 4000 rows of sample with 3 time-steps(3 columns) of a bone size corresponding to size of bone measured in 3 different months.

I am done with the basic model. Now I want to be sure if my understanding of the model is correct.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(units=10, input_shape=(3,1),use_bias=True,bias_initializer='zeros',activation="relu",kernel_initializer="random_uniform"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")) 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
model.summary()


model.fit(trainX,train_op, epochs=100, batch_size=50, verbose=2)
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
```

Following are my few doubts around this model :

1. Here `return_sequences` is False , then shouldn't I get only the last output from RNN layer. Why the output is of shape(None, 10) from RNN layer? I assumed it should be (sample size,1) .

Also my below mentioned logic is flawed but I need to resolve it which is :

Units corresponds to output units. Initially my guess was that since there are 3 time-steps there has to be 3 output units but I was surprised that even if give units= 128 or 10,1 the model worked. How and why it is happening ? This question along with the above one confuses me more.

2. input_shape corresponds to -[sample size, number of time steps, features]. Here, I am measuring 1 bone size over 3 time periods. Is my understanding correct when I say the input shape is (sample size, 3,1) ? Moreover, I have confusion regarding how numpy represents 3d array. It seems, to get required dimension I need to input as - #features, observations/sample_size, timesteps . Do I have to reshape my inputs according to how numpy represents 3d or should i let it be. ?

Moreover, how can I build a model if i have different set of features measured over different time frame or have various time steps ? How can i incorporate with the above model.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you get the last output, which is a 10-dimensional vector, not a one-dimensional vector, so getting shape `(samples, 10)` is correct.
2. Number of units has nothing to do with timesteps, the number of timesteps is how many times the neurons are applied recurrently, so its orthogonal to the number of features or units.
3. Yes, shape of your inputs should be `(samples, 3, 1)` and the `input_shape` should be `(3, 1)`, all of this is correct in your code. I am not sure what you are talking about on "how numpy represents 3d array", the shape is clear, numpy does not do any modifications to input shapes.

Comment: Could be please tell what is units.? The way I am relating timesteps and unit is that each RNN cell produce an output for a input. Since there are 3 time steps there has to be 3 RNN cells. Is RNN cell same as units ?

Comment: No, units is the number of neurons, the dimension of the output of the RNN cell

Comment: So, units are the number of hidden states for a RNN cell.? So in this case each RNN cell would have 10 hidden states. Since the return sequences is FALSE, the last RNN cell would out 10 values corresponding to 10 hidden states ? Am i right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct, its the dimensionality of the hidden state

Comment: Thanks, according to your experience does having more units help ?